# When embedding a pdf, page no longer scrolls

Tags: html, css, html-object, html-pdf

```
<object data="NAME.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="1200px">
  <p>Alternative text<a href="NAME.pdf">My CV</a></p>
</object>
```

So let's say I embed my pdf into my page like this, so that the entire page is the pdf document. [EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWUPT.jpg)

The issue I get is that when you scroll inside the object (pdf), it only scrolls the object, so when it's full screen nothing happens. I would like the user to be able to scroll the site, not the pdf.

Also is there a way to change the object pdf background color?

Thanks for the help, there doesn't seem to be much documentation on this. If you have any other suggestions on integrating a full-page pdf please let me know. I am using pure HTML/CSS.

Comment: Please provide the link of your page where you are getting the error.

Comment: this is in a local environment. but for example this page: http://mamulova.com/about-me.html

Comment: as you can see, you cannot scroll in the page. I want to enable scrolling.

Comment: I can scroll the page. Is there anything I am missing. Even in full screen mode the page can be scrolled.

Comment: @FitnessRegiment What environment are you testing with? (hardwars, OS, browsers). No problems here on FF or Chrome in Windows 8.1.

Comment: Windows 10, Chrome. Where is your mouse located? When my mouse is anywhere on the pdf object, I cannot scroll.

Comment: Are you trying to scroll the page using keyboard keys?

Comment: no  with the scroll wheel of my mouse, while the mouse is over the pdf.

Comment: I hope you guys understand what I mean. This isn't an issue with the pdf, it's that I don't want the user to scroll in the pdf, I want the scroll wheel to correspond to the website, so that the user can scroll down and see the footer.

Comment: @FitnessRegiment This is not the same question you had before. In the example page in your comment, the object is not always as high as the PDF, so it has an internal scrollbar, allowing the user to scroll the document up and down in its object. Only when the object's scrollbar is at its bottom does the page itself scroll again. This is the desired behaviour, otherwise the user couldn't get to see the bottom of the document!

Comment: Now if you want to avoid having a second scrollbar in the object, what you need to do is ensure the object is as high as the document. So that the whole document is visible in the page and only the page itself is scrollable.

Comment: The whole document is visible to me, you have an internal scroll bar? Are you at 100%? What resolution is your display? it could be that I have a 4k display.

Comment: @FitnessRegiment I can resize my browser window.